# How can I bin/bucket a data.frame by birthyears

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, binning

I have a data.frame with three columns: a token, year of birth and number of contacts. The birthyears range from 1934 to 2020 and I don't want individual years but 5-year groups like 2000-2005, 2006-2010 and so on to later visualize the contact count per age group.

I already found the `cut` function like [this](https://www.jdatalab.com/data_science_and_data_mining/2017/01/30/data-binning-plot.html):

```r
# set up cut-off values 
breaks <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
# specify interval/bin labels
tags <- c("[0-2)","[2-4)", "[4-6)", "[6-8)", "[8-10)", "[10-12)","[12-14)", "[14-16)","[16-18)", "[18-20)")
# bucketing values into bins
group_tags <- cut(v$MeanEducation, 
                  breaks=breaks, 
                  include.lowest=TRUE, 
                  right=FALSE, 
                  labels=tags)
```

However in this example I'd have to set a vector of breaks and labels manually.

Is there a solution to automize this? Like beginning the first bucket at the next lower by 5 dividable year than the minimum in my dataframe. Analogue at the top end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set up binning and labels during the generation of the plot of you use ggplot2. Why don’t you try to generate the plot and folks can weigh in on how to tweak it to get the right output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tags` that you have defined are created by default by `cut` function you don't have to add them manually. Moreover, you can use `seq` to create sequence of breaks and `paste` to generate labels programatically.

```
#Generate data
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(10)
x
#[1]  3 10  2  8  6  9  1  7  5  4
#Create breaks
breaks <- seq(0, 10, 2)
#Create labels
labels <- paste(head(breaks, -1), tail(breaks, -1), sep = '-')

#Without labels
cut(x, breaks)

#[1] (2,4]  (8,10] (0,2]  (6,8]  (4,6]  (8,10] (0,2]  (6,8]  (4,6]  (2,4] 
#Levels: (0,2] (2,4] (4,6] (6,8] (8,10]

#With labels
cut(x, breaks, labels)
#[1] 2-4  8-10 0-2  6-8  4-6  8-10 0-2  6-8  4-6  2-4 
#Levels: 0-2 2-4 4-6 6-8 8-10
```